# Optional Synchronous Interface to Asynchronous Functions

Tags: python, asynchronous, tornado, synchronous

I'm writing a library which is using Tornado Web's `tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient` to make requests which gives my code a `async` interface of:

```
async def my_library_function():
    return await ...
```

I want to make this interface optionally serial if the user provides a kwarg - something like: `serial=True`. Though you can't obviously call a function defined with the `async` keyword from a normal function without `await`. This would be ideal - though almost certain imposible in the language at the moment:

```
async def here_we_go():
    result = await my_library_function()
    result = my_library_function(serial=True)
```

I'm not been able to find anything online where someones come up with a nice solution to this. I don't want to have to reimplement basically the same code without the `awaits` splattered throughout.

Is this something that can be solved or would it need support from the language?

---

## Solution (though use Jesse's instead - explained below)

Jesse's solution below is pretty much what I'm going to go with. I did end up getting the interface I originally wanted by using a decorator. Something like this:

```
import asyncio
from functools import wraps


def serializable(f):
    @wraps(f)
    def wrapper(*args, asynchronous=False, **kwargs):
        if asynchronous:
            return f(*args, **kwargs)
        else:
            # Get pythons current execution thread and use that
            loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
            return loop.run_until_complete(f(*args, **kwargs))
    return wrapper
```

This gives you this interface:

```
result = await my_library_function(asynchronous=True)
result = my_library_function(asynchronous=False)
```

I sanity checked this on python's async mailing list and I was lucky enough to have Guido respond and he politely shot it down for this reason:

> Code smell -- being able to call the same function both asynchronously 
>   and synchronously is highly surprising. Also it violates the rule of 
>   thumb that the value of an argument shouldn't affect the return type.

Nice to know it's possible though if not considered a great interface. Guido essentially suggested Jesse's answer and introducing the wrapping function as a helper util in the library instead of hiding it in a decorator.

Comment: perhaps write the code as a generator based coroutine and then use the [types.coroutine()](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#types-coroutine) to create an asynchronous equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you want to call such a function synchronously, use [run_until_complete](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.AbstractEventLoop.run_until_complete):

```
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(here_we_go())
```

Of course, if you do this often in your code, you should come up with an abbreviation for this statement, perhaps just:

```
def sync(fn, *args, **kwargs):
    return asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(fn(*args, **kwargs))
```

Then you could do:

```
result = sync(here_we_go)
```